# HTML / Javascript - Specifying a local file to be used instead of upload using input file field

Tags: javascript, xlsx

First of all many thanks for the precious help this community provides to newbies and experts in the field.
I'm currently developing a tool that parses an XLSX file and outputs the tables into the HTML.
At the moment I'm using a script provided by Catamphetamine: https://catamphetamine.github.io/read-excel-file/read-excel-file.min.js and it is working great.
The script imports the XLSX file using the below code:

```
           input.addEventListener('change', function() {
          readXlsxFile(input.files[0], {sheet: 3} ,{ dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YY' }).then(function(data) {
            // `data` is an array of rows
            // each row being an array of cells.
            //var dataString = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)

            ranContactData = data


            document.getElementById('result-table3').innerHTML = '<table>' + data.map(row => '<tr>' + row.map(cell => `<td>${cell === null ? '' : cell}</td>`).join('') + '</tr>').join('') + '</table>'
          }, (error) => {
            console.error(error)
            alert("Error while parsing Excel file. See console output for the error stack trace.")
          })

        })
```

I totally understand that the first line tells the script is waiting for a change in the input field and then uses the file selected to proceed with the function readXlsxFile.
What i want to do is, to be replace the input field with an object that will store my file, since the file used will always be the same, there is no need to have the input field and when i launch the readXlsxFile function, instead of using input.files[0] as the first parameter, I would specify something like "myLocalFile" with the file i want to use.
I also know, by debuging the script, that the object i want to create to store the file must be of type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet but i don't know how to accomplish this.

Hope you guys can provide me with some assistance.
Thanks

UPDATE:

I tried the following code:

```
   var f = new File([], 'ONCALL.xlsx', {type:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
```

Then use it in readXlsxFile like this:

```
  readXlsxFile(f, {sheet: 3} ,{ dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YY' }).then(function(data) {
        // `data` is an array of rows
        // each row being an array of cells.
        //var dataString = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)

        ranContactData = data


        document.getElementById('result-table3').innerHTML = '<table>' + data.map(row 
         => '<tr>' + row.map(cell => `<td>${cell === null ? '' : cell}</td>`).join('') + '</tr>').join('') + 
     '</table>'
      }, (error) => {
        console.error(error)
        alert("Error while parsing Excel file. See console output for the error stack trace.")
      })
```

got no luck with it, i'm receiving the following error in the console:

```
index.html:414 Error: End of data reached (data length = 0, asked index = 4). Corrupted zip ?
at i.checkIndex (DataReader.js:26)
at i.checkOffset (DataReader.js:17)
at i.readData (Uint8ArrayReader.js:13)
at i.readString (DataReader.js:75)
at u.isSignature (zipEntries.js:40)
at u.readEndOfCentral (zipEntries.js:165)
at u.load (zipEntries.js:256)
at load.js:49
readXlsxFile.then @ index.html:414
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ index.html:404
```

Comment: I am curious how are you able to feed a local file to your code?

Comment: I managed to accomplish that by running a virtual http server extension for chrome. With that i was able to overcome the cross-origins limitation.
After taht was only a matter of reading the file using xmlHTTPrequest and specifying the URL to be the local file, something like: http://localhost/excelfile.xlsx